# FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo el siguiente problema al momento de querer ejecutar el comando flutter run en mi proyecto:
ya he intentado
1 - ejecutar el comando flutter clean, flutter pub get.
2 - He eliminado la carpeta 'C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\flutter_local_notifications-16.3.0\android\build.gradle' y vuelto a ejecutar los comandos flutter clean, flutter pub get.

pero el error continua, como puedo resolverlo?

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\flutter_local_notifications-16.3.0\android\build.gradle' line: 24
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':flutter_local_notifications'.

> No signature of method: build_47tpq7cudo7tn28xi6g0pma82.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_47tpq7cudo7tn28xi6g0pma82$_run_closure2) values: [build_47tpq7cudo7tn28xi6g0pma82$_run_closure2@1fcc618a]

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 468

Comment: Prueba a usar el comando "flutter pub cache repair "